# Basic Pytorch tensor multiplication and addition

Tags: python, pytorch

I just realize I lack some very basic pytorch tensor math. How do I do the following with a pytorch tensor?

`lab_rs = (lab_rs * [100, 255, 255] - [0, 128, 128])`

This works well in numpy. It's an image with shape (3, 512, 1024) and I want to multiply and subtract values from each color channel individually

The error I get trying the same with a tensor is:

```
TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index
```

Comment: Assuming `lab_rs` is a numpy array, I can't get your statement to execute.  I get`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,512,1024) (3,)` Can you please provide a fully-working code example?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure all your operands can be [broadcast](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html) to the same dimensions:

```py
lab_rs = lab_rs * torch.tensor([[[100]], [[255]], [[255.]]]) - torch.tensor([[[0]], [[128]], [[128.]]])
```

Comment: Great. This works. Even if I don't understand broadcast completely. Many thanks!